# Lombok не генерирует геттеры и сеттеры

Tags: java, lombok

В "Annotation processors" галочка стоит на "Enable annotation processing", плагин "Lombok Plugin" установлен последней версии, использую Intellij IDEA 2019.2.1 Ultimate, на проекте использую Gradle

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Author implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String authorName;
    private String title;
}
```

Господа шарящие, что я упустил?

Comment: ставьте аннотацию @Getter/@Setter над полем, которое хотите открыть, а не над классом

Comment: @Maxgmer я пробовал для каждого поля отдельно их ставить и один раз на классом, результат был один и тот же, геттеры/сеттеры не генерились(

Comment: можете показать свой gradle файл еще тогда? И еще можно попробовать File->Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: @Maxgmer File->Invalidate caches and restart пробовал - не помогло, а gradle файл конкретно какой нужен? Я с ним первый раз работаю, build.gradle?

Comment: был такой глюк - решил полным удалением всех папок и файлов, кроме непосредственно проекта

Comment: у вас Lombok в gradle то прописан?

Comment: @Алексей г  в зависимостях то конечно, так бы я заметил ещё при "прописывании" аннотаций

Comment: @temp_temp и тем не менее в build.gradle чего-то не хватает.. к тому же не совсем понятно, что подразумевается под не генерирует ? вероятно, в gradle файле не прописан ломбок в качестве процессора аннотаций

Comment: @keekkenen Да, вы правы на счёт процессора аннотаций, хрестоматийную вещь упустил) Благо зашёл доки почитать, там собственно даже написано что делать) Собственно, спасибо всем)